# How to change the hdri background

Tags: image, hdri

I have a simple model and i have used hdri environment image in cycles. I have uncheck the option in camera to hide the environment image. When i press shit+z to render i get the black background. I want that black color to be change to white or other color.How can i change the color.

[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris/49403#49403

Comment: Or  enable **film: transparent** (to have a transparent backgound) and add the background in the compositor using **Alpha over**.

Comment: @cegaton thanks for the little small option transparent click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are the settings you need to change
[image: Using custom colors for transparent background]

Comment: You can do the same without the RGB node as well and set the background color directly on the Alpha Over node