# How to get rid of HDR reflection?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, hdri

I have this scene where i want to keep the HDR lighting, but not necessarily the reflection in the windows. I want the reflection to be blue, sky coloured. How can i reflect the sky part of the HDR in the windows[image]. Is this possible?

Comment: This may help, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris