# Making a material that does not reflect HDR

Tags: materials

I'm trying to make a glossy, reflective material that will reflect other objects, (preferably with the Principled shader), but I'd like it if it did not reflect the HDR I'm using to light the scene.

Could somebody please tell me how to achieve this?

EDIT To be more specific, in this scene I'm using the lighting method described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris), and I'm trying to have the HDR that's lighting the scene be the one not reflected by the material.

Comment: If the HDR is lighting the scene, it reflects off all the surfaces. Do you want the HDR to be visible only for diffuse surfaces and be invisible for glossy surfaces? This you can do with the *Light Path node*.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I'd like it to be invisible only for one single material, if possible. The light of the HDR bouncing off of other objects should be reflected so that those objects can be seen in the reflection, but the HDR itself should not.

Comment: This maybe will be added at some point but without writing a python script I'm pretty sure this isn't possible as of 2.9.3. In almost every situation you will be anyway wanting to change it in the world shader type, if you start modifying these values for every object individually then things will be looking incorrect. So in some way this is a safeguard. It probably out of exactly that reason will never be added.