# Can I use an HDRI for reflections only, and not have its light affect the scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, hdri

I have my scene perfectly lit without the use of a HDRI, however I would now like to add one just so I can have some world reflections in my glossy objects. I can't seem to get the HDRI reflecting in my objects without it also adding light to the scene, though. Is there any way to use an HDRI solely for reflections, and not have its light also affect the scene? I am using Cycles.

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can use the *Is Glossy Ray* input from the *Light Path* node.
With this setup, your World color stays the same, but reflection rays show your HDRI.

*Color 1 is your world background, Color 2 is your HDRI.*

[image]

*Using Using Light Path input*
[image]

*Using solid grey World color*
[image]

Comment: Hi, I still can't get your set-up to work. I've added a screenshot as an example, but the reflections and overall light still seem to be tied together. In my example, I would like to have reflections in the sphere but not have the scene light up too. If I set the background strength to zero, obviously there are zero reflections and everything is dark but for my scene lights. If I increase the strength, reflections appear as I want, but the rest of the scene lights up too. Am I missing something? Sorry if I'm just being dumb. I'm new to Blender. Thanks.

https://imgur.com/a/WqF6mWc

Comment: Hello, you're not dumb, it's complicated :). *All materials* reflect light to some degree, so you cannot *entirely eliminate* lighting changes to your scene. The reflections of your HDRI bounce around and can affect other objects.

Comment: To sum up: What you're looking for isn't possible (because physics), but you can get closer with these solutions :). As in real world photography, Photoshop might be required for perfect result.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you need to go into the *Properties* panel > *World* > *Ray Visibility*, and deactivate *Diffuse*.

[image]

Comment: Hey :). Just tried this, and all diffuse rays render as black. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: hello, I'm not sure what you mean, if you deactivate Diffuse, the HDRI won't enlighten the scene anymore, so you need to create some lights, your solution is good though

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thanks :).