# Rotate HDRI image only?

Tags: hdri

Is it possible to rotate an HDRI background without rotating the lighting it gives off? I know that you can go into shading, world, and then add a mapping node and that rotates it, but that also rotates the light, I wanna keep the light in the same place but rotate the background. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @brockmann Ello! Thanks for your suggestion, but that seems to have changed since then, I can't even find the Alpha option under Render Properties. Thank you though! :)

Comment: EZ. It's still the same principle and nothing has changed really. If you are using cycles just enable the *Transparent* checkbox (*Render Properties > Film > Transparent*). Also the link points to another cycles answer as well. Otherwise I'd recommend to provide more details.

Comment: @brockmann Tysm! Works perfectly! :D

Comment: Just made an edit to: [How to use multiple HDRIs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49403/31447) ... both options in one pretty nice answer (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in EEVEE and Cycles without compositing by using the [*Light Path Node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html#light-path-node)*>is Camera Ray* output.

A node setup like below will allow you to do just what you are asking:

[image]

---

This produces the following result in the EEVEE viewport:

[image]

Notice that the background rotates, but the lighting does not.