# Does Higher light power effect render times?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

does light power strength effect render times?
because i also use blender's interior hdri to light up my scene. But i figure i would use higher light power to create a better lighting than the hdri.
Should i mix it up the two or just use the light with higher power strength to reduce render times. Because the change in detail is minor, but it looks more dramatic with the actual light.
oh another question, does the hdri also cause the light to bounce?

Comment: The ray starts at the camera and goes backwards until it seeks a light source.  In the hdri's case, any time a ray bounces off to infinity it reports back the color and light intensity of the hdri in that direction.

Comment: So multiple lights can increase noise, therefore render time, since a ray will only report back color info for one light per ray.  Multiple importance sampling may help here, I haven't dug into it far enough.

Comment: Consider this camera ray light path solution to brighten the hdri while displaying normal intensity to the camera - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49403/110840